# No Mac Installer Certificate Found in Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, provisioning-profile

I just renewed my provisioning profiles and my Mac device profile but I keep getting this error when refreshing the Xcode Organizer:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears when your OS X Developer Certificate or OS X Distribution Certificate has been submitted to the Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles tool for approval, but has yet to be approved by a Team Admin or the Team Agent.

If you are either of these roles on your OS X Developer program account, login to the [Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles tool > Mac Apps > Certificates > Pending](https://developer.apple.com/account/mac/certificate/certificateList.action?type=pending) and approve your pending OS X Developer Certificate.  Otherwise, contact someone with Team Admin rights or the Team Agent, and request that your certificate be approved.  Once this happens, click the refresh button and you should be able to continue through the rest of the update process.

In the interim, if you need to get updated certificates or profiles for your iOS account, login to the [Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles tool](https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action) and manually download the files you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't have the Mac Installer Distribution certificate installed. Once I downloaded that certificate and refreshed Xcode, the error disappeared.